# Attempting to split all 4 digit numbers in spreadsheet cells with regex and formulas

Tags: regex, split, google-sheets, formulas

I’m currently running into some difficulties with splitting and regular expressions in a Google spreadsheet.  I’m attempting to split the contents of a cell across a row, but only pulling out sequences of four consecutive digits (representing years) and only using cell formulas (not functions).  Eventually, this formula would apply to an entire column, but I’ve limited it to a single cell for the time being.  For example, given a cell “I2” with the contents:

> 2009; Library of Congress; 1939-1945; 23rd 1984; 16

I need a result (placed in “J2, K2, L2, M2, etc.”) like:

> 2009   1939    1945    1984

This sample cell is as representative as I’m aware of for various possibilities that are likely to come up, though the number of entries between semicolons varies from one to many.  In my own attempts so far, I’ve ended up with two formulas that are close to what I need, but both fall short.

1) The first formula is:

> =ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(I$2, "[^\d\-\;]", ""),"-", ";"), ";"))

which achieves (in "J2, K2, L2, M2, N2"):

> 2009   1939    1945    231984  16

2) The second formula is:

> =ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(I$2, "[^\d]", ";"), "[^\d\-\;]", ""),"-", ";"), ";"))

which gets me (in "J2, K2, L2, M2, N2, O2"):

> 2009   1939    1945    23  1984    16

I’ve been trying to think of a way to limit the formula’s returns with "\d{4}", for example, but no combination or alterations I’ve made so far have been successful.  Does anyone have any insight which would solve this problem?

Comment: Does google regex have word boundary tokens?  If so, then use the pattern `\b\d{4}\b`

Comment: I haven't run across any references to Google's ability to use word boundary tokens so far, no; I thought that would do it as well.  I just tried substituting some of the portions with your suggestion again, but it returned errors.  What particular alterations with "\b\d{4}\b" did you have in mind based on the above formulas?

Comment: In Excel, an array formula can return an array of values.  So I would have thought that in `Sheets`, something like `ArrayFormula(REGEXEXTRACT(your_string,"\b\d{4}\b"))` would return an array of all the four digit matches. However, I am not familiar with `Sheets` and was not able to get that to return other than the first match.  Oh, and the `\b` token is listed as available in the `RE` documentation used by `Sheets`.  So the problem seems to be returning all of the matches, instead of just the first one.

Comment: Figured out one way of returning all the matches using `REGEXEXTRACT`.  It seems cumbersome compared with Excel, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work, although I am no expert in Sheets, and there may be more efficient methods.

Apparently if you use capture groups, `REGEXEXTRACT` will return an array of values.  This method, however, seems to require that you know the exact number of matches to be extracted.

So the following seems to work:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT($I2,REPT("(\b\d{4}\b).*?",(len($I2)-len(REGEXREPLACE($I2,"\b\d{4}\b","")))/4))
```

How it works:

> First compute the number of matches in the string:

```
=(len(I2)-len(REGEXREPLACE(I2,"\b\d{4}\b","")))/4
```

> Next, create a regex expression incorporating the regex the correct number of times:

```
REPT("(\b\d{4}\b).*?", ...Above_formula...)
```

And finally, we put it all together in our final formula above.

Of course, if you **know** that the number of matches will always be four (4), there is no need for constructing the regex string in this manner, you can just hard code it.

**EDIT** To eliminate unwanted zero's if there are no matches, test to see if there are any matches using `REGEXMATCH`: eg:

```
=ArrayFormula(if(REGEXMATCH($I2,"\b\d{4}\b"),(value(REGEXEXTRACT($I2,REPT("(\b\d{4}\b).*?",(len($I2)-len(REGEXREPLACE($I2,"\b\d{4}\b","")))/4)))),""))
```

Comment: That also seems to work well, yes; thanks!

The only issue with the result is that the values returned register as "False" with (for example) =ISNUMBER(J2).  I'm also running a quartile analysis on the array returned, so that's pretty necessary.  Is there a way to translate the results into number format so they register as "True"?  I tried adding VALUE to the formula, but doing so cuts down the results to the very first number (2009).

Comment: @A.K. Just enter it as an array formula (with the VALUE function), and it will return an array of Numbers.

Comment: That worked perfectly, Ron; thank you!  The last sticking point that's come up here is that, although all the rows display the dates as they should, they each also fill up all the remaining columns with "0" if there's nothing that meets the criteria.  This continues up to the furthest column that's been populated with a date, so it ends up looking like a table with more 0s than anything (throwing off an AVERAGE function on it all). Is there a way to successfully layer in an IF statement that returns blankspace "" if there are no dates or further dates?  My attempts so far have returned errors.

Comment: Huh? Your original question has nothing in it regarding dates, nor should the formula I have recommended be returning a date.  Also, when I copy the formula down from J2, only the columns with four digit numbers populate, so if the is one match, then just column J; if there are two: J & K, etc.

Comment: You’re right; I’m using the 4 digit number to represent a date, but the results are in number format and not in date format (which is intentional on my part; my mistake for not being clear!).  To get the number value array as you suggested, I altered the formula to: =ArrayFormula(Value(REGEXEXTRACT(I2:I,REPT("(\b\d{4}\b).*?",(len(I2:I)-len(REGEXREPLACE(I2:I,"\b\d{4}\b","")))/4))))
That’s what gets me lines like: 
"2009 1939 1945 1984", "0 0 0 0", and "2005 1910 0 0" from "2009; Library of Congress; 1939-1945; 23rd 1984; 16", "Library of Congress", and "2005; 1910"

Comment: What was your reason for changing `$I2`  to `I2:I`?  I am not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: Removing the anchor “$” was a little arbitrary on my part because I didn’t need it.  Apologies if I’m covering something you already know or if I’m not clear on what you mean, but the use of "I2:I" instead of just “I2” or "I2:[some row in I]" is what allowed the formula to auto-populate down the entire column in my sheet once it was put into an array formula.

Comment: `I2:I` seems to be what is causing the problem.  I just selected J2 and "dragged-down" to fill the column, and do not see your issue.

Comment: Changing it back to "I2" and dragging does fix the multiple zeroes in the different cell rows, yes.  It still leaves a single zero if I use it to read a cell that doesn't have a 4 digit number in it, like "Library of Congress" or "12" on their own.  It's good to know that that's where the additional zeroes come from, though!

Comment: @A.K. I have edited my answer to handle the situation for zero matches in a line.  If this satisfies your question, please mark my response as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use this formula, perhaps replacing the colon as split character with another character that's not likely to occur in source strings.

```
=filter(split(regexreplace(I$2, "\D+", ":"), ":"), len(split(regexreplace(I$2, "\D+", ":"), ":"))=4)
```

Explanation: it's a way around regex limitations in Google RE2 engine. Instead of looking for the pattern, we look for the anti-pattern (anything that is not digit) and replace it with the separator, then split. What remains is only substrings composed of digits, so we filter them so that only 4-character substrings remain.

Comment: That's just about perfect; thanks, ttarchala!

The only additional question I have is how to now extend the formula to the entire column without manually dragging it to a given point.  It looks like the use of FILTER is preventing the use of I2:I with an Array Formula to automatically populate all the cells in the column, which is what I did with both of the previous formulas.  If I try that, I get the error message:

>"FILTER range must be a single row or a single column."

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to use the user defined function approach for that. I would like myself to know how to force arrayformula to loop the way I want...